# Как склонять название улицы (Рашетова улица)?

Tags: склонение

Как склоняется *"Рашетова улица"*? (Человек, удостоенный такой чести, носил фамилию Рашет, а не Рашетов).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Как любое притяжательное прилагательное

[с суффиксами -ов- (ев), -ин-, образованное от собственных имён лиц, животных, мифологических существ](http://rustest.edu.ru/rules/orfografia/propis/3172/)

Это правило, собственно, на прописную-строчную,

привожу его полностью:

> С прописной буквы пишутся притяжательные прилагательные с суффиксами
>   -ов- (ев), -ин-, образованные от собственных имён лиц, животных, мифологических существ: Марсов гнев, Одиссеевы странствия, Машино
>   платье, Шарикова будка.
>
> Со строчной буквы пишутся притяжательные прилагательные с суффиксами
>   -ов- (ев), -ин-, образованные от собственных  имён  лиц,   животных,   мифологических  су­ществ, если они употреблены в переносном значении
>   (чаще они входят в состав устойчивых сочетаний, фразеологиз­мов):
>   ахиллесова пята, прометеев огонь, сизифов труд.

К исходному *Рашет* можно спокойно примерить (на предмет склоняемости) любое имя собственное на *-ов-*: Марс, Сизиф.

Comment: *Это правило, собственно, на прописную-строчную,* - нет слов. ))) Одни буквы.

Answer (score 0):

И. Рашетова улица
Р. Рашетовой улицы
Д. Рашетовой улице
В. Рашетову улицу
Т. Рашетовой улицей
П. (о) Рашетовой улице

Как звали увековеченного, если он вообще был, тут никакой не играет.
По форме это краткое притяжательное прилагательное и склоняться может только так.

---

А вообще Питеру везет на такие названия. Есть небезызвестная Бармалеева улица не совсем ясного происхождения, которую тоже пытаются "пересклонять" по непонятно какому образцу, вплоть до "улицы Бармалеева". Так вот, она тоже склоняется по тому же образцу.

Comment: "Шёл по Рашетовой улице...". Из этого следует, что улица называется "Рашетовая", а не "Рашетова". Как с этим-то быть?

Comment: Не следут и никак. Принять к сведению, что название улицы (и не только) не всегда однозначно восстанавливается из форм косвенных падежей. Если читающий/слушающий не знаком с правильным названием и для пишущего/говорящего это критично, то следует воспользоваться другой формой высказывания. Типа *Шел по  улице,  с названием "улица Рашетова"*.